# Update state when user press back button in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I use react-navigation for manage routes. This is my Home component:

```
class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
      this.state = {
         userProfile: {
            firstname: 'John',
            avatar: 'john-profile.png',
            location: 'Canada',
         }
      }
   }

   componentDidMount() {
      AsyncStorage.getItem('userProfile', (errs, result) => {
         this.setState({userProfile: JSON.parse(result)});
      });
   }

   render() {
      return (
         <View>
            <Image src="{this.state.userProfile.avatar}" />
            <Text>Firstname: {this.state.userProfile.firstname}</Text>
            <Text>Location: {this.state.userProfile.location}</Text>
         </View>
      );
   }
}
```

And this is the Profile screen:

```
class ProfileScreen extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
      this.state = {
         userProfile: null,
      }
   }

   componentDidMount() {
      AsyncStorage.getItem('userProfile', (errs, result) => {
         this.setState({userProfile: JSON.parse(result)});
      });
   }

   save() {

      var userSavedProfile = this.state.userProfile;

      userSavedProfile.firstname = "Peter";
      userSavedProfile.avatar = "peter-avatar.png";
      userSavedProfile.location = "EEUU";

      this.setState({userProfile: userSavedProfile});

      AsyncStorage.setItem('userProfile',     JSON.stringify(this.state.userProfile), () => {});

   }

   render() {
      return (
         <View>
            <Button title="Save" onPress={() => this.save()}  />
         </View>
      );
   }
}
```

When I save the new user information and I press back button in header (react-navigation) the user profile is old, firstname = John, etc... How update state from Home when user press back button and refresh data?

Comment: I was also facing the same issue but I resolved it. Can you please tell me, how are you moving to profile screen?
Is home is a parent class for profile screen ?

Comment: please let me know then I will post my code here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `BackHandler` from react-native
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/backhandler.html
You can change state inside function of backhandler

Comment: But backhandler is used in this case on ProfileScreen for back to HomeScreen. In the documentation I see not apply for iOs devices. I need refresh state in Home when user press back button from ProfileScreen.

Comment: From what I understood you want to up date state in HomeScreen  from an action in ProfileScreen  for this declare a function in Home Screen  like getData() write all your logic in HomeScreen getData and then send it as props to ProfileScreen and call the function in onPress of the button

Answer (score 0):

I think that your application would need a state manager, where you could store your user information and access it anywhere in the app. You should take a look at [Redux](http://redux.js.org). It would fit your needs and the info in your Home screen would automatically update.

Answer (score 0):

but for anyone who will need this functionality in there react native application here is the solution you can try.
using react navigation.

```
import {withNavigationFocus} from "react-navigation";
class Profile extends Component {
    ...
}
export default withNavigationFocus(Profile);
```

Answer (score 0):

There can be two workarounds check it out -

**1** Send callback in params

```
class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
      this.state = {
         userProfile: {
            firstname: 'John',
            avatar: 'john-profile.png',
            location: 'Canada',
         }
      }

      this.getUserData = this.getUserData.bind(this);
   }

   componentDidMount() {
       this.getUserData;
   }

   getUserData = () =>{
         AsyncStorage.getItem('userProfile', (errs, result) => {
            this.setState({userProfile: JSON.parse(result)});
         });
    }

   render() {
      return (
         <View>
            <Image src="{this.state.userProfile.avatar}" />
            <Text onPress={()=>this.props.navigation.navigate('ProfileScreen', this.getUserData)}>Firstname: {this.state.userProfile.firstname}</Text>
            <Text>Location: {this.state.userProfile.location}</Text>
         </View>
      );
   }
}
class ProfileScreen extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
      this.state = {
         userProfile: null,
      }
   }

   componentDidMount() {
      AsyncStorage.getItem('userProfile', (errs, result) => {
         this.setState({userProfile: JSON.parse(result)});
      });
   }

   save() {

      var userSavedProfile = this.state.userProfile;

      userSavedProfile.firstname = "Peter";
      userSavedProfile.avatar = "peter-avatar.png";
      userSavedProfile.location = "EEUU";

      this.setState({userProfile: userSavedProfile});

      AsyncStorage.setItem('userProfile',     JSON.stringify(this.state.userProfile), () => {});

      //this is the magic
      this.props.navigation.state.params.getUserData();

   }

   render() {
      return (
         <View>
            <Button title="Save" onPress={() => this.save()}  />
         </View>
      );
   }
}
```

**2** On HomeScreen Constructor add this (Dirty one)

```
this.props.navigation.addListener(
      'didFocus',
      payload => {
        this.setState({is_updated:true});
      }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `componentDidUpdate(){...}` insted `componentDidMount(){}`